# How to remove shopping cart from WooCommerce plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Virtue Theme in Wordpress and have installed the WooCommerce plugin for setting up my online store. I want to remove the shopping cart function completely and instead place an order form on individual product page.
Help is sought to remove the shopping cart.

Comment: Do you want to skip the checkout page as well?

Comment: For future visitors: [One Page Checkout](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/) would be perfect for this.

Answer (score 5):

this is my experienced with Woocommerce about remove carts function. I added this code in functions.php in my Virtue themes.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

In [this Web](http://latiafashion.com) I used that code. I Hope that's can solve your probelms. Thank you :)

Comment: I added this to the woocommerce.php page in the WC() function

Answer (score 0):

Using firefox right click on the cart and [open inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector). Find the css used on the right panel. Then, in modify theme, add custom css like:

```
.woocommerce-active .site-header .site-header-cart {
  display: none !important;
}
```

(*In the above code «.woocommerce-active .site-header .site-header-cart» was in the right panel of "inspector". While in modify mode you can instantly see the result, so make some tries if CSS name is not the correct one.*)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was finding the class associated with cart using the inspect tool in Chrome (any browser should provide the same feature).  Customize the theme appearance and add custom CSS.

```
 .cart-button {
display: none !important;
}
```

Watch the video showing the steps (there's no audio) at https://www.loom.com/share/9f9d1a8d3fb346e0b954c8c26f06a926

Answer (score -2):

To remove shopping cart from WooCommerce plugin in Wordpress, select the Disable option in Menu cart:Display

Go to Appearance>Customize>WooCommerce>General>Menu cart

[image]

Comment: I don't see this section in the Appearance page on my Woocommerce install.

Comment: The Appearance > Customize options are theme specific. Probably not many themes will support this option. I would follow something like [Dhyta Wan answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064868/2082479)